# Insert PHP Arrays as MYSQL columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I am trying to add dynamic array values from two arrays into mysql table as columns, several rows at a time. I have created a loop for that.
When I run it it produces an error, stating that I have an error in MYSQL syntax. When I try to run the query statement that is produced directly in phpMyAdmin it runs fine. So the syntax shouldn't be an issue. Thanks for any help.

```
function addSystemDataTanks ($db, $tankNamesArray, $tankVolumesArray)
{

  global $tankNamesArray;
  global $tankVolumesArray;
  global $noOfTanks;

  $statement = "replace into tanks (TANK_NAME, TANK_VOLUME) ";
  $statement .= "values ";

  for ($i = 0; $i < $noOfTanks; $i++) {

  $statement.= "('".$tankNamesArray[$i]."', '".$tankVolumesArray[$i]."'), ";
  }
  $statement.= rtrim($statement, ',');

  $result = mysqli_query($db, $statement);


  if ($result)
  {
    return true;
  }else{
    $errno = mysqli_errno($db);
    echo "{h4}MySQL Error No: ".mysqli_errno($db)."</h4>";
      echo "{h4}MySQL Error: ".mysqli_error($db)."</h4>";
      echo "{h4}SQL: ".$statement."</h4>";
      echo "{h4}MySQL Affected Rows: ".mysqli_affected_rows($db)."</h4>";
  }
  return 'NotAdded';
}
```

Comment: What is the actual query which gets executed here?

Comment: remove point? `$statement= rtrim($statement, ',');`

Comment: What @splash58 said and use `rtrim()` for both the comma and the space or it will not work: `rtrim($statement, ' ,')`. And you should probably use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: What @jeroen said OR remove last space character from the line `$statement.= "('".$tankNamesArray[$i]."', '".$tankVolumesArray[$i]."'), ";`

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems so far:

- First: where are you assigning a value to `$noOfTanks` ? your `for` loop depends on that value, however, i don't see it being assigned which means it is currently resulting in `NULL`, thus your loop not iterating.
- Second: This line `$statement .= rtrim($statement, ',');` is concatenating to the original `$statement` variable thus ending up with this:

  ```
  'REPLACE INTO tanks (TANK_NAME, TANK_VOLUME) values REPLACE INTO tanks (TANK_NAME, TANK_VOLUME) values '
  ```

  I'm assuming you want to re-assign after your `trim`, in that case do this:

  ```
  $statement = rtrim($statement, ',');
  ```